# ASP simple image uploader

Tags: asp.net

Is there a method inside ASP.Net to let me upload images or files in a very minimum script files?

Basically im looking for a script that will let me upload files or script by bulk on my server but there are few constrains on my server, like I don't have access on database I also don't have an access to an FTP account and my web hosting provider just provided me a web interface to upload files one-by-one.

I am hoping I can override their system by uploading few ASP files on their server and running those to have my own uploader then I can use it to upload my own files in bulk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this site](http://www.aspupload.com/manual_simple.html#2_3) that contains some content on uploading files under ASP. Section 2.3 has the specifics for uploading with ASP.Net.